# Inner evaluation in EL 2.2

Tags: jsf-2, el

I have some code as follows:

```
<f:loadBundle basename="messages.application" var="prop" />
<ui:param name="currentUserAttr" value="#{prop['currentUser']}" /> 
// currentUserAttr=currentUserVal
<h1>Welcome #{sessionScope.currentUserAttr.name}</h1> // should be evaludated to sessionScope.currentUserVal.name
```

I want to get the value of `currentUserAttr` then when reading from session replacing the attr with its value then getting the value from session, any ideas how to do that in EL 2.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the brace notation as well if you want to use a dynamic key.

```
<h1>Welcome #{sessionScope[currentUserAttr].name}</h1>
```